# Jest testing: How can I test that a function was called with specific parameters within axios call

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios, jestjs, try-catch

I have a very simple axios call that deletes a record. If successful, it will call the notify function (custom function) with specific parameters. I don't actually want the notify to run, but all I want to check is that it's called with those specific params when it gets inside the then.

```
export function deleteRecord(id) {
    return axios
        .delete(`/${id}`) 
        .then(() => notify('success', 'Delete successful'))
        .catch(() => notify('error', 'Delete failed'));
}
```

I've been going down the rabbit hole jest.fn(), spyOn and toHaveBeenCalledWith but I'm just stuck. This is where I've ended up:

```
it('deleteRecord success', async () => {
        const id = 1;
        const notify = jest.fn()

        axios.delete.mockResolvedValueOnce({ status: 200 });
        await deleteRecord(id);
        expect(notify).toHaveBeenCalledWith('success', 'Delete successful');
        
    });
```

This is what I get as an error.

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "success", "Rolled back"

    Number of calls: 0
```

All I want is to test that it gets to the successful notify specifically, because I want to then test for the failed notification in another test. I just don't understand what I'm missing. I've gone through so many other threads, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock the `notify` function.

```js
import { deleteRecord } from './deleteRecord';

jest.mock('./notify', () => jest.fn());

it('deleteRecord success', async () => {
  const id = 1;
  const notify = require('./notify');

  axios.delete.mockResolvedValueOnce({ status: 200 });
  await deleteRecord(id);
  expect(notify).toHaveBeenCalledWith('success', 'Delete successful');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method to see if it works:

1. In your test folder make another folder called "__mocks__".(I believe that jest knows that anything in that folder are mock data)
2. In the "__mocks__" folder, make a js file named "notify" with the function notify in it. And since you do not care what it does, that function can be empty.

```
         export function notify(arg1, arg2){
    }
```

3. Now here is how your test should look like:

```
import {notify} from './notify';

jest.mock('./notify'); //<-- this is pointing to your actual js file where your real notify function is.

it('deleteRecord success', async () => {
        const id = 1;

        axios.delete.mockResolvedValueOnce({ status: 200 });
        await deleteRecord(id);
        expect(notify).toHaveBeenCalledWith('success', 'Delete successful');
        
    });
```

Hopefully, this works for you.